# Huawei Cluster Map and View Marker

Tags: react-native, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-map-kit

I am creating a project in React Native for Huawei and i use this library: "@hmscore/react-native-hms-map".

When creating the map, how can I place the view inside the markup?
In MapView I can put  inside and draw anything, however in HMSMarker it doesn't allow me, is there a way?

---

2. Groups only join when there are at least 6 marks together, is there a way to make groups of 2 marks together?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Marker can be customized in icon mode:

You can find the parameter description here:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-References/marker-0000001051150162#section8565252375

And the sample code:

```
      <HMSMarker
        icon={{
          uri: Image.resolveAssetSource(
            require("../assets/galata-tower.png")
          ).uri,
          width: 140,
          height: 150,
        }}
      >
```

2. The min marker number in cluster cannot be changed.

Comment: I can't put a View inside the HMSMarker tag?

`<HMSMarker>
      <View>
          <Text>Hello</Text>
     </View>
</HMSMarker>`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set title and snippet for the marker, it is supported like :
[image: sample]
Or you can define a InfoWindow.

But if you want to define the view of the marker, you cannot use "View" directly.